# How to manually insert column into a HTML table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML table which I am rendering with JSON data, what I am trying to do is to create a column using JavaScript which is not coming as json data

- I have a table having 2 columns, and I want to add 3rd manually as `Quantity`
- using JavaScript it can be done but I am not getting the idea of that

**My snippet**

```js
var tableData = [
    { "Item Code": "1001", "Item Name": "Beverages", },
    { "Item Code": "2003", "Item Name": "Juices", },
    { "Item Code": "1004", "Item Name": "Soups", },
    { "Item Code": "2005", "Item Name": "Cookies", },
];

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];

      if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTable(tableData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="form1">
  <div class="row position-relative">
    
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class=" w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="save">
      <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to add a third column named as `quantity` with data as `0`. I am not getting the idea how can I do that.

Comment: There's no such a thing in HTML tables like column, there are just rows and cells. You've to iterate thorugh the rows in the table, and insert a cell to an appropriate index. If the table is not containing row or cell spans, the task should be quite trivial when using `insertCell` method.

Comment: @Teemu so here in my html table what approach should i use

Comment: You could add the cell for the extra column in `for .. j` loop, just iterate it one step longer, and check for index 2 etc.

Comment: @Teemu can you help me with some small piece of snippet please

Comment: Why can't you just push new heading into `col` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help you. It will add the column it self when page load.

```js
var tableData = [
    { "Item Code": "1001", "Item Name": "Beverages", },
    { "Item Code": "2003", "Item Name": "Juices", },
    { "Item Code": "1004", "Item Name": "Soups", },
    { "Item Code": "2005", "Item Name": "Cookies", },
];

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];

      if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTable(tableData);

function addCol(){

var colname = "Quantity";
var colValue = 0;

var tablehead = $("#HourlysalesSummary tr[class='text-center head']")[0].append($('<th>'+colname+'</th>')[0]);
var tableRow = $("#HourlysalesSummary tr");
var i =1;

while(i < tableRow.length){

tableRow[i].append($('<td>'+colValue+'</td>')[0]);
i++;

}

}

addCol();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


<form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="form1">
  <div class="row position-relative">
    
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class=" w-100" id="HourlysalesSummary"></table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="save">
      <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i dont wanna do this on button click ,it should populate by itself on page load

Comment: Just push into a function and call it where you want.

Comment: i tried and removed the button as well as function it says undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
function addTable(tableData) {
  tableData.forEach(item=>item.Quantity='')
...
}
```

Add above line in your addTable function and check